# Invoking multiple docker commands via python

Tags: python, docker, subprocess

I am trying to invoke a docker instance from python subprocess (windows / wsl).
Let's just assume that the docker I need to run is a simple `docker run -it busybox` (it's not going to be that, but it's a shell for experimenting) but once loaded I need to insert programmatically (asynchronous or blocked, either way is fine) some commands for git to pull some sources and then compile them and deploy them (before invoking docker, I am asking the user to choose a tag from a set of repos).

So far using the normal `subprocess.Popen` I was able to tap in to docker, but I need to have this persistent until I leave docker interactive shell (from busybox).

Is this possible to be done, or once I get the subprocess done it stops at the next command (as it happens now)?

(PS I can post some of my code, but I need to clean up some bits first)

Comment: The [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) will be safer and more robust than trying to use `subprocess.Popen`.  The workflow you're describing sounds like it'd be better matched by having a user clone the repository, check out the right branch themselves, and then run `docker build`.

Comment: The docker is already being built and provisioned by another tool, so I can only interact at runtime (not build). So my first step is to get the ````docker ps```` first.

Comment: @DavidMaze docker sdk looks interesting though. Is there a way to tap into a running docker and execute commands?

Comment: Yes, there is in the exec part of the docker SDK, seems cool enough!

Answer (score 0):

Can you possibly do a simple while loop?  My other thoughts would be if all the commands are the same each time they are called, put them in a batch file and call the batch from python.  All I can come up with without code.

Comment: I thought of that as well with a bash script but this will need to be injected to the docker first (docker cp) as this is not a standard distribution file (to the docker image I refered to). I am repreparing the code I used and will post in a bit.